# How can I get around this new CCS error in Code editor and my Nativescript project

Tags: visual-studio-code, nativescript

Have a project in NS and lately in Code editor started getting this error:

`Error: [UriError]: If a URI contains an authority component, then the path component must either be empty or begin with a slash ("/") character
    at /Users/mini/Desktop/Visual Studio`

I narrowed it down to lines like below in my css file:

`background-image: url('res://hotels');`

That has always worked.

What can I do?

Comment: That is the `vscode` issue. https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/41987

Comment: Is the issue happening with a specific version of VSCode? Let me know if you are experiencing the same with the latest version of VSCode.

Comment: I'm using 1.37.1 on Mac and it's happening. I get the error only if I start editing the file.